# $f \in End_K(V)$, char$(K)=2$ which does not satisfy an equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra

I was working on the following proof and have completed it but I am trying to understand why

char$(K)\neq2$ is demanded.

---

Let $V$ be a finitely dimensional vector space over $K$ with char$(K)\neq2$ and let $f \in End_K(V)$. Show that $$f^2=Id_V$$ $$\iff$$

There exists an ordered basis $B$ of $V$ and $i, k \in \mathbb{N_0}$ such that

$$c_{B,B}(f)=\begin{bmatrix}
    E_i & 0 \\
    0 & -E_k
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Is there an example of an $f \in End_K(V)$ with char$(K)=2$ such that the equivalency does not hold? I have used char$(K)\neq2$ to show that $V=ker(f-Id_V) \oplus ker(f+Id_V)$, so with that there exist bases of those subspaces that form an ordered base of $V$ with $f=Id_V$ for the first and $f=-Id_V$ for the second kernel which proves "$\implies$".

Are there any counterexamples when char$(K)=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in characteristic $2$, the equation $f^2-Id_V=0_V$ is equivalent to $(f-Id_V)^2=0_V$, which suggests that we should take a Jordan block of size $2$ with eigenvalue $1$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Showing that the Jordan block cannot be transformed into the demanded form of $c_{B,B}(f)$ is then shown using the lack of similarity, correct?

Comment: @B.Swan You can note, for example, that the RHS $\begin{bmatrix}E_i & 0 \\ 0 & -E_k\end{bmatrix}$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Thats very neat since if there exists an ordered basis $B$ of $V$ with $c_{B,B}(f)=\lambda E_n$ for a $\lambda \in K$ then $c_{C,C}(f)=\lambda E_n$ for any ordered basis $C$, which would be sufficient establish the counterexample.